# Word for expressing oneself non-verbally

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking not specifically for a word, but a description of someone who expresses their feelings, emotions in an authentic manner.  Someone who doesn't have to say much to convey their state; one can understand them by being around them, feeling rapport  not verbally.

Character examples:  Joe, from *Nymphomaniac*, or the main character of *Under the Skin*.

Comment: Maybe their stature or mannerisms are expressive. Maybe they are "easy to read"

Comment: People who expresses themselves well non-verbally are **non-verbal**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of communicating non-verbally.

If you want to highlight that they talk through gestures, try:

**gesticulative** if you want an adjective, or **gesticulator** for a noun

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gesticulate):

> He describes the fascinating journey along the evolutionary path that ‘converted us from wild gesticulators to smooth talkers.’

Answer (score 0):

You can define this kind of person as being [transparent:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/transparent)

> - candid; frank; open.

or [an open book](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+an+open+book):

> - if someone is an open book, it is easy to know what they are thinking and feeling. *Sarah's an open book, so you'll know right away if she doesn't like the present you've bought her.*

The Free Dictionary